Function not looping
I have created a class with a method and imported it to the main script.
class Character:

    # INIT METHOD
    def __init__(self, name, char_class, hp, max_hp, damage) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.char_class = char_class
        self.hp = hp
        self.max_hp = max_hp
        self.damage = damage

    # ATTACK METHOD
    def attack(self, target) -> None:
        target.hp -= self.damage
        target.hp = max(target.hp, 0)

        print(f"{self.name} dealt {self.damage} damage to {target.name}!")

On my main code, I created a fight() function to simulate a fight and constantly update each of the targets' health.
while True:

    # DISPLAY HERO INFO
    print(f"\n{'#' * 18 + '#' * len(current_room)}\n You are in the {current_room}.\n{'#' * 18 + '#' * len(current_room)}")


    # FIGHT TODO : MAKE IT WORK :|
    def fight():

        boss = Character(name="Minotaur", char_class="Minotaur", hp=50, max_hp=50, damage=4)
        hero = Character(name="Warrior", char_class="Warrior", hp=50, max_hp=50, damage=5)

        hero.attack(boss)
        boss.attack(hero)

        print(f"\n{hero.name} has {hero.hp} HP.")
        print(f"{boss.name} has {boss.hp} HP.")

        input()

        if hero.hp == 0:
            death()

        elif hero.hp > 0: # TODO : ITS REPEATING THE ATTACKS, HP NOT DRAINING
            pass

        elif boss.hp == 0:
            boss_list.append(the_map[current_room]["Enemy"])
            print(f"Congratulations! You killed the {boss} and got stronger!")

[...]
        elif current_room == "Ruins":

            if "Enemy" in the_map[current_room].keys():

                enemy = the_map[current_room]["Enemy"]

                if enemy not in boss_list:
                    print(f"\nThere's a {enemy} here.")
                    print("You have to DEFEAT IT.")
                    print("What would you like to do?")
                    print("\n1 - FIGHT THE ENEMY")
                    user_input = input("> ")
                    print(" ")

                    if user_input == "1":
                        fight()

                    else:
                        print("Invalid command. Try something else.\n")

                else:
                    print("\nYou have already defeated the enemy!")


Except it doesn't keep looping until someone's health reaches 0, it just goes back to the first print(), as shown in the image. Not only that, but when I managed to make it kind of loop, it never updated the hp, instead it just repeats the same thing over and over again.


In the code you've posted, you never call fight(). This isn't the actual code you're running, and it's not possible to debug this fragment.

@davidlowryduda sorry! just updated the question.

You have shown us where fight() is defined, but not where it is called.

Also, it's odd to have a function definition inside of a loop.  What is the point of defining a function more than once?

I see that you have defined your function inside the while loop. By any chance are you calling the same function over and over again in while?
The function essentially creates new Warrior and Minotaur objects in every iteration of while. Essentially making them both stuck at 46 and 45 HP respectively.

@DarshanAS so I defined the function outside of the while loop, still gives me the same exact result. I am calling the same function in while, yes! Essentially, there are three separate locations and three seperate enemies, and I didn't want to manually write the same if statement for every single one of these instances, so I thought of creating a function. Would it be better if I just manually coded it?

You shouldn't create boss and hero inside the function. Create them once, and pass them as arguments to the function.

@JohnGordon I was having issues with a list, and thought it wouldn't be an issue if I defined the function inside the while loop. I'm new to python still, which explains a lot. Is it bad to define a function inside a loop?

And you probably shouldn't call the function recursively, just call it repeatedly in the loop.

it's no bad, per se, but rarely needed to keep recreating the function.

Like @Barmar said, you should create the boss and hero outside the function. In fact outside the while loop, to be precise.
Post that, it doesn't matter if your function is defined inside or outside the while loop. Although I'd recommend keeping it outside to avoid re-defining the function in each iteration.

As a general rule, only put code inside a loop if it needs to be done repeatedly. Usually this will mean that it depends on something that changes each time through the loop. Since there's just one boss and hero, and how they're created doesn't depend on anything from the loop, you should only create them once before the loop.

It's a common beginner mistake to put initialization code inside the loop, then they wonder why the changes they make don't persist.

@Barmar I see! If I wanted to make more than one boss, what would be best to do, then? I created the boss and hero outside the while loop and defined the fight() function inside of it, still gives me the same result. It feels like I have tried every single iteration of inside/outside of the loop, and it still gives me the same result. Is it because I'm calling it more than once?

I suggest you simplify what you're doing to get a handle on the basics.

The loop should look something like while True: fight(boss, hero) followed by code that checks the status of the two characters and decides whether the loop should end.

@Barmar I guess I'm getting ahead of myself. Thank you for the help, anyway!
